# How to show full images in a div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to show the full image regardless of its dimensions in a div. The dimensions of the div are: Width:400px and Height:400px [400x400] . So even if an image is larger than the div, I want the entire image to be displayed in the div. the image should maintain its aspect ratio. How can I achieve this with CSS or jQuery? Is this possible without manipulating the image with PHP or any other script?

[Sorry for incorrect grammar or bad english]

Comment: So you want the div to expand with the image or?

Comment: Sorry. No. The div should remain static. The image should adjust according to the div. I can get the image to fill 100% of width and not go any more in width, but if the image is more in height, the height of the div increases. I want the div to be static and not changing as per the image.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you add it as a background you can add:
`background-size: contain;`

If you use `img` tags, then:
`object-fit: contain;`

For better compatibility with older browsers, you should use the background method.

---

Edit:
Just wanted to put this here, in case someone else needs it:

1. No object-fit: https://jsfiddle.net/ke8yu22d/
2. With object-fit: https://jsfiddle.net/yf5psqyL/
3. As background: https://jsfiddle.net/vqy316L6/

Answer (score 0):

```
height:160px;
width:160px;
background-image: url('images/Science.png');
background-position:center center;
background-repeat:no-repeat;
background-clip:content-box;
```

Comment: While this code may resolve the OP's issue, it is best to include an explanation as to how your code addresses the OP's issue. In this way, future visitors can learn from your post, and apply it to their own code. SO is not a coding service, but a resource for knowledge. Also, high quality, complete answers are more likely to be upvoted. These features, along with the requirement that all posts are self-contained, are some of the strengths of SO as a platform, that differentiates it from forums. You can edit to add additional info &/or to supplement your explanations with source documentation.